# Laravel Mix breaks package with `npm run dev`

Tags: javascript, node.js, laravel, ecmascript-6, laravel-mix

I have a nodejs package written with ES6 functionalities as 'let', the spread operator (...) and default values of a function's arguments.

The thing is when I run `npm run production` of Laravel Mix, an error shows up, which is the following :

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                 
 error
/js/app.js from UglifyJs
Unexpected token: name (DateTime) [./~/vdatetime/src/datetime.js:3,0]
[/js/app.js:40347,4]

npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-72-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "production"
npm ERR! node v7.4.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.1.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! @ production: `cross-env NODE_ENV=production 
node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --
config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
```

(Seems to be the `let` operator that is in cause at line 3)

But when I try `npm run dev`, everything works as intended.
Any idea why it is unable to transpile the code ?

Comment: show us the line with the `let name` then

Comment: Doesn't the spread operator require Babel stage 2 presets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uglify cannot parse ES6, it will throw syntax errors. Convert to ES5 first, post-process your generated JS with babel, or use a different minifier.

Comment: I added babel to the package that is executed on the `beforepublishOnly` script (which runs when you type `npm publish`) so that the published script is transpiled to ES5 when Uglify comes to minify it